# GitHub copilot can't log in the github,print the error

Tags: pycharm, github-copilot

Sign in failed. Reason: Request signInInitiate failed with message: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3128, request id: 3, error code: -32603

i need a ways to slove the problem.........

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm guessing you're asking "How do I fix this?"  Please include some details as to what you are doing to get this error?  Are you using a script?  What does it look like?   (Please redact any credentials in your script).  As posted in its current form, there's no way to help you.  Sure, we could *guess* what it might be, but I think you prefer concrete answers as opposed to guesses (which may or may not work).

Comment: But a possible guess is your firewall.  (from https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/67446)